# How can I create a WebGL mesh from a JSON string in gwt-g3d?

Tags: json, gwt, webgl, mesh

How can I create a mesh (instance of StaticMesh) from a JSON string in gwt-g3d (http://code.google.com/p/gwt-g3d/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the JSON string is static, you can load it as an ExternalMeshResource (see http://code.google.com/p/gwt-g3d/source/browse/trunk/gwt-g3d-test/src/gwt/g3d/test/client/Lesson14Demo.java on how to use this resource).

If not, you can use `JSONParser.parse(jsonString)` to get a JSON value object, then do something like

```
Float32Array.create(jsonObj.get(fieldName).isArray().getJavaScriptObject().<JsArrayNumber>cast());
```

to gets a `TypeArray` that you can pass to `StaticMesh`. The `fieldName` above depends on your json string object. For example, if you json looks something like:

```
{
  "vertexPositions" : [0, 1, 2, ...]
  "vertexNormals" : [0, 1, 0, ...]
  "indices" : [0, 1, 2, ...]
}
```

then your `fieldName` can be "vertexPositions", "vertexNormals", and "indices".  (Note that the indices array is usually of type `Uint16Array` instead of `Float32Array`).  See the [implementation of AbstractMeshResource](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-g3d/source/browse/trunk/gwt-g3d/src/gwt/g3d/resources/client/impl/AbstractMeshResource.java) for more information